# C++ cant use respond string from GET requests retrieved by ExpressJS API for anything else than printing

Tags: c++, node.js, string, api, express

Scenario:
Im writing a c++ program which should retrieve files and strings from an expressJS API..
Downloading txt.files with curlRequests works perfectly but as soon as i try to retrieve plain strings, they can only be used for printing..

Problem: When trying to do anything with the response from my GET request (from the expressjs api), my response doesnt get treated as a string.

```
string myText = curlRequest.GetText("/templates/names");
string myTextB = "react.txt, scss.txt"
cout << myText << endl; // prints"react.txt, scss.txt"
cout << myTextB << endl; // prints "react.txt, scss.txt"
cout << stringHelper.GetSubstringPos(myText, "scss") << endl; // printsstring::npos
cout << stringHelper.GetSubstringPos(myTextB, "scss") << endl; // printsposition of 's' as expected
```

Here is my GetText function of the curlrequest.h in c++

```
   string GetText(string ACTIONURL) {
        CURL* curl;
        CURLcode curlRes;
        string res;
        string url = templateCreator.APIURL + ACTIONURL;
        curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
        curl = curl_easy_init();
        if (curl) {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1L);
            curlRes = curl_easy_perform(curl);
            res = curlRes;
            if (curlRes == CURLE_HTTP_RETURNED_ERROR) {
                res = "FAILED";
            }
            else if (curlRes != CURLE_OK) {
                fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(curlRes));
                res = "FAILED";
            }
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        }
        curl_global_cleanup();
        return res;
    }
```

Here is the route in expressjs (receiving the request and responding with a string)

```
router.get('/names', function(req, res, next) {
  var str = "react.txt, scss.txt, example.txt";
  res.send(str);
});

// I also tried sending a buffer but as its sended as string i face the same problem..
// C++ could decode the buffer ..
router.get('/buf', function(req, res, next) {
  let data = 'hello world: (1 + 2 !== 4)';
  let buff = new Buffer.from(data);
  let base64data = buff.toString('base64');

  console.log(base64data);
  res.send(base64data);
});
```

Retrieving textfiles from my expressjs API is not a problem..

```
void GetFile(string ACTIONURL, string OUTDIR) {
    CURL* curl;
    FILE* fp;
    CURLcode res;
    string url = templateCreator.APIURL + ACTIONURL;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl)
    {
        fopen_s(&fp, OUTDIR.c_str(), "wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return;
}
```

(After download I can read those line by line and store in a vector).

Still im hoping to get sending actual strings working..
Does anyone have a clue why im facing problems here?
I literally spent days on this unexpected 'small' issue already..

Comment: Why are you trying to return strings like `"FAILED"`? Note `curl_easy_perform` does not return a string, it returns a `CURLcode`, so it isn't quite clear what you expect from `res = curlRes;` If you need a string, set up a custom callback with `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`.

Comment: thanks @n.'pronouns'm. your comment helped me quiet much. If you want to answer it as actual answer, i can mark it as solved later..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @n.'pronouns'm.
I Updated my function and realised that `res = curlRes` was a nobrainer..
Also the checks for valid response is gone for now.

```
//those 2 lines and a write_to_string function were missing and `res = curlRes` should do their job
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_to_string);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);
```

The following 2 functions replace my GetText function now, and everything works as expected.

```
size_t write_to_string(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t count, void* stream) {
    ((string*)stream)->append((char*)ptr, 0, size * count);
    return size * count;
}

string GetText(string ACTIONURL) {
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;
    string response;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, templateCreator.APIURL + ACTIONURL.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_to_string);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if (res != CURLE_OK) {
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return response;
}
```

Thank you! I found the fix on 1 or 2 questions earlier too but was not aware that this was the actual problem. Working with strings is possible now!